# Set chroot color In .bashrc

Tags: bash

I'm trying to fine tune my .bashrc file and was hoping that I could get chroot to be a different color other than default white. My rc file is pretty close to the default other than some git stuff and the coloration scheme. The problem is that I can't seem to set chroot to red ahead of the calls to debian_chroot without problems.. Here's an excerpt of what I think is relevant.

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
if [ "$color_prompt"=yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") '
    PS1="$PS1\[\033[00m\]\u@\h:\n\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ "
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \$ '
fi

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

How can I set the chroot color to red in my bash prompt?

Comment: Figured it out on my own. In my case, I was using Python's **localenv**, which has its own rc type file named 'activate' in /localenv/bin/ . Add your color before the line where (`basename \"VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1 is set to PS1.

Comment: answer your own question.